# jQuery get value from input type=number containing dash / minus

Tags: jquery, html, input, numbers

I have an `<input type="number">` as I want the numeric keyboard on mobile device.

I need to get this value in javascript/jquery, which is normally just `$element.val()`.

This works as long as the field contains a number `[0-9]`*, but if it contains a dash "-" I don't get any value at all.

How can I get the value?, or can I use `<input type="text">`; but still force the mobile device to use a numeric keyboard?

Comment: So I could change it to text and add a pattern attribute [0-9]* which will also chaange the keyboard, however on my iPhone that gives me the telephone keyboard, thus I can not add a dash, changing the pattern to [0-9-]* will only give me the default keyboard...